# Unable to remove ACE from ACL

Tags: powershell, permissions, file-permissions, acl, ntfs

We have want to clear an NTFS `ACL` of a folder completely and only have the `ACL` populated with the `ACE` `Builtin\Administrator : Full Control`. The code below works fine for most folders but fails on one specific folder:

```bsh
$Path = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\Gemensam'

$BuiltinAdmin = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'Builtin\Administrators'
$AdminFullControlAce = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    $BuiltinAdmin,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit',
    [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
)

(Get-Acl $Path).Access

$FolderItem = Get-Item -Path $Path -EA Stop
$Acl = $FolderItem.GetAccessControl()

Write-Verbose 'Set owner'
$Acl.SetOwner($BuiltinAdmin)
$FolderItem.SetAccessControl($Acl)

Write-Verbose 'Disable inheritance'
$Acl = $FolderItem.GetAccessControl()
$Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
$FolderItem.SetAccessControl($Acl)

Write-Verbose 'Remove all ACEs from the ACL'
$Acl = $FolderItem.GetAccessControl()
$Acl.Access.ForEach({$Acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)})

Write-Verbose 'Add Admin and set the new ACL'
$acl.AddAccessRule($AdminFullControlAce)
$FolderItem.SetAccessControl($Acl)

Write-Verbose 'ACL corrected'
(Get-Acl $Path).Access
```

The output of this code is:

```bsh
FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : GROUPHC\SWE CEM KVB EV
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

VERBOSE: Set owner
VERBOSE: Disable inheritance
VERBOSE: Remove all ACEs from the ACL
True
True
VERBOSE: Add Admin and set the new ACL
VERBOSE: ACL corrected
FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : GROUPHC\SWE CEM KVB EV
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

For one reason or another it seems to be impossible to remove the `ACE` of `GROUPHC\SWE CEM KVB EV`. Even with `Get-ACL` and `Set-ACL` [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573308/removing-all-acl-on-folder-with-powershell) doesn't work. We've also tried to push the `ACL` after every change as [indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514751/unable-to-remove-directory-aces), but that doesn't work either. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection?view=netframework-4.8) the inheritance is properly removed, so it can't be an inherited `ACE`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

To avoid issues with ownership we run the following code first:

```bsh
#region Get super powers
    $AdjustTokenPrivileges = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class TokenManipulator
{
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr
phtok);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name,
ref long pluid);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct TokPriv1Luid
{
public int Count;
public long Luid;
public int Attr;
}
internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED = 0x00000000;
internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
public static bool AddPrivilege(string privilege)
{
try
{
bool retVal;
TokPriv1Luid tp;
IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
tp.Count = 1;
tp.Luid = 0;
tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
return retVal;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
}
public static bool RemovePrivilege(string privilege)
{
try
{
bool retVal;
TokPriv1Luid tp;
IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
tp.Count = 1;
tp.Luid = 0;
tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED;
retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
return retVal;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
}
}
"@

Try {
    Write-Verbose 'Get super powers'
    Add-Type $AdjustTokenPrivileges
    [void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege('SeRestorePrivilege')
    [void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege('SeBackupPrivilege')
    [void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege('SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege')
}
Catch {
    throw "Failed getting super powers: $_"
}
#endregion
```

Comment: It's possible that there's a file within the folder which is not actually owned or has permissions accessible by the administrator and therefore you can't take ownership of it to change it.
There's a PS module in the gallery - PSCX - which contains "Set-Privilege" commands to override file permissions and take ownership

Comment: You used PSCX? What syntax?

Comment: Not really a valid test if you still have file permissions on that file as you'd just be able to take ownership anyway....

Comment: Updated my answer to show you we do this already.

Comment: What happens if you overwrite the current ACL with a brand new one? `$newACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity` instead of trying to remove the existing acces rules?

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thank you very much Theo. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Theo from the comments we found a workaround for the problem. We just have to create an empty `ACL` and then add our properties to the object, after that it can simply be applied:

```bsh
$Path = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\Gemensam'

$BuiltinAdmin = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'Builtin\Administrators'
$AdminFullControlAce = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    $BuiltinAdmin,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit',
    [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
)

#region Create new ACL
$NewAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
$NewAcl.SetOwner($BuiltinAdmin)
$NewAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)
$NewAcl.AddAccessRule($AdminFullControlAce)
#endregion

$FolderItem = Get-Item -Path $Path -EA Stop
$FolderItem.SetAccessControl($NewAcl)


$FolderAcl = $FolderItem.GetAccessControl()
$FolderAcl.Access | select IdentityReference, FileSystemRights
```

Or apply the ACL twice:

```bsh
$M = Get-Item -Path 'C:\YourFolder'
$Acl = $M.GetAccessControl()

$BuiltinAdmin = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'Builtin\Administrators'
$InheritedDirAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
$InheritedDirAcl.SetOwner($BuiltinAdmin)
$InheritedDirAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false,$false)

# This is a workaround for non inherited permissions
# that do not get removed when simply applying the new ACL
$Acl.Access | ForEach-Object {
    $Acl.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific($_)
}
$M.SetAccessControl($Acl)
$M.SetAccessControl($InheritedDirAcl)
```

[Related issue here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5770f0bd-fddd-442b-b917-daf88ff28b10/removing-modifysync-ntfs-permissions-using-removeaccessruleall-in-powershell?forum=Offtopic).

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above:

```
Import-Module PSCX

Set-Privilege (new-object Pscx.Interop.TokenPrivilege "SeRestorePrivilege", $true) # Necessary to set Owner Permissions
Set-Privilege (new-object Pscx.Interop.TokenPrivilege "SeBackupPrivilege", $true) # Necessary to bypass Traverse Checking
Set-Privilege (new-object Pscx.Interop.TokenPrivilege "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege", $true) # Necessary to override FilePermissions & take Ownership
```

Now use Get/Set ACL commands recursively on the target

Comment: Updated the question to show you that this is not the issue